# What is the correct syntax for grouping rows

Tags: excel, vba

Syntax error using the following code.
Both variables `LR1` and `LR2` were declared as `integers`:

```
sh.Rows("& LR1+1 &":"& LR2-1 &").Group 'Syntax error
```

No syntax error if hardcoded numbers are used:

```
sh.Rows("27:29").Group
```

Comment: `sh.Rows(LR + 1 & ":" & LR2 - 1)`. But don't use `Integer`, use `Long`.

Comment: @bigben  Thank you I will do, but that wont solve my problem.  I always struggle when I have to use the &

Comment: Why does that not solve your problem?  What problem is remaining after using the proper syntax as shown by @BigBen?

Comment: Apologies, working.  I copied it wrong...too many hrs coding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your question is how strings and concatenating work:

The `&` forces string concatenation which means it will take strings or non-string types (but not all types like arrays) like your integer/long variables and combine them into a string.

In your code you have two strings and a character outside the string. `"& LR1+1 &":"& LR2-1 &"`

String 1: `"& LR1+1 &"` This is a valid string but `Rows` can't parse it.

Character: `:` This is causing the syntax error

String 2: `"& LR2-1 &"` This is a valid string but `Rows` can't parse it.

This is throwing a syntax error because `:` is not a valid character and isn't in a  string.

an `&` needs to be outside the string otherwise it is just a part of the string.
`"&"` will not concatenate.

What BigBen did in his comment is take your variables (which you have inside a string and as such are not variables they are just characters in a string that happen to look like your variables) and concatenate them into a string that `Rows` can work with.

So `LR1 + 1 & ":" & LR2 - 1` Is taking the Value in `LR1` and adding 1, then combining that number with `":"`, then subtracting 1 from `LR2` and combining that into the string as well.

if `LR1 = 10` and `LR2 = 20` your final output will be:

`"11:19"`

You can check what your string will look like with `debug.print`

Answer (score 4):

Variables don't belong inside quotes.

```
sh.Rows(LR + 1 & ":" & LR2 - 1)
```

Also, [use Long instead of Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long).

Comment: @MrT - See Warcupine's answer as well. The hard-coded `"27:29"` needs quotes because it is a String. If you're using variables, `LR + 1 & ":" & LR2 - 1` results in a string that doesn't need quotes. But regardless, variables don't belong inside quotes.